# How to search in a jpql query by a discriminator value

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot 3

I use discriminator, i have many class (only three is show here)

```
@Table
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "contributor_code", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Contributor{
...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(Contributeur.DESIGNER)
public class ContributorDesigner extends Contributor{
...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(Contributeur.TRUCKER)
public class ContributorTrucker extends Contributor{
...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(Contributeur.TEACHER)
public class ContributorTeacher extends Contributor{
...
}
```

Is there a way to do a query in jpql with a condition on the discriminator value?

I search to do a select to get ContributorDesigner and ContributorTrucker

Comment: If you want a condition to select the objects of the specific class, simply `select c from ContributorDesigner`  or `select c from ContributorTrucker.`

Comment: I search in the same query to get some specific contributor

Comment: In this post you will see how to check the `TYPE` corresponding to the discrimintator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884249/java-jpa-query-with-specified-inherited-type